# Fixed width and height of the UIImage using Swift (AutoLayout)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, autolayout, fixed-width

I am trying to put my image at the center & want to keep the width & height of the image fixed.

I have tried adding constraints : equal width, equal height and have also added a constraint to keep some padding below the label.

When I run it, the size of the image is scaled up and it goes to the top right.

I have tried a lot of permutations & combinations to get it where it in the middle, not of them as worked so far.

Comment: Maybe share a screen shot

Comment: it's margin rather than padding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement, set the constraints

- Horizontally in container
- Vertically in container
- Width
- Height

Not `equal width`, `equal height`. And I believe going to the top right is because there's no valid horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following constraints to uiimageview :

(I have give fixed height and width of 300, you can have your own variants)

[image]

And the output will be...

[image]